# FFMPEG Screen Capture Issue

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, twitch

Sorry if this has been solved but I couldn't find it.

I'm trying to screen capture using ffmpeg and stream it to Twitch. I have both x11grab and libx264 enabled but when I give it the input for my monitor it keeps returning:

```
:0.0+0,0: Protocol not found
```

I confirmed that :0.0 is indeed my $DISPLAY variable, and even if I call that directly in my script with the same error. My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Stream Variables
STREAM_KEY="<not shown>"
INRES="1680x1050"
OUTRES="1024x768"
FPS="30"
BITRATE="1266k"
BUFFER="1266k"
AUDIO_BITRATE="160k"

ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -framerate $FRAMERATE -video_size $INRES \
   -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate $BITRATE -bufsize $BUFFER \
   -vf "scale=$OUTRES, format=yuv420p" -g $(expr $FPS \* 2) -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a $AUDIO_BITRATE \
   -f flv rtmp://liva-jfk.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY
```

I'm on Debian Jessie(Testing) and ffmpeg and associated packages come from deb-multimedia. I'm curious if maybe someone here can see something I might have missed.

Sidenote: I know the same display is called in programs like ScreenStudio and they work, but aren't as flexible. I've tried using obs-studio for linux and it crashes with an illegal command when I start recording which makes me wonder if this is a system problem that might be the cause of that.

Comment: `$FRAMERATE` is undefined. Did you mean $FPS?

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `-` before `video_size`.

`-f x11grab -framerate $FRAMERATE -video_size $INRES`

**Why 'protocol not found'?**: Because it thinks the `x11grab` format applies to some input named `video_size` and it can't deduce the format of the actual input `:0.0+0,0`.

**Update:** `$FRAMERATE` is undefined. You meant to use `$FPS`. Now it thinks that the whole thing after `-framerate` is the value and you're in the same situation as above.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but that was actually a typo in pasting my script. It already read -video_size. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Updated the answer. Got any more typos, uninitialized values : ) ?

Comment: Well how about that, my mistake was even more obvious than initially thought. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: I usually do an `echo` before running the command the first time. It helps catching issues like this.